# How to get public folder absolute path in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to get a public folder path in shopware 6 in order to create a directory inside using the filesystem. Does anyone have an idea about it?

Comment: Do you mean the folder path or the base URL?

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look at the service

`shopware.filesystem.public` which is defined in

`vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DependencyInjection/filesystem.xml` as

```
   <service class="League\Flysystem\FilesystemInterface" id="shopware.filesystem.public" public="true">
        <factory service="Shopware\Core\Framework\Adapter\Filesystem\FilesystemFactory" method="factory"/>
        <argument>%shopware.filesystem.public%</argument>
    </service>
```

When you inject this service, you can call

```
$publicFileSystem->createDir('folder')
```

to create your folder.

That does not exactly answer the question on how to get the path - but you usually don't need that, as you woult not interact directly with the filesystem, but via `Flysystem` classes instead.

If you really need the path, you could try something like

```
$publicFileSystem->getMetaData('.')['path']
```

This is untested by me and as written before, you might just not need the path. Also keep in mind, that the underlying filesystem might not even be a local storage.

Comment: I inject the service in the constructor but I get an error when I try to use it: `$fileSystem must not be accessed before initialization`. Do you know what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not exactly bulletproof, but most of the time you can also use `getcwd();`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

I mostly use it for writing debug-files like `error_log(print_r($data, true)."\n", 3, getcwd().'/error.log');`

Comment: Are you sure that gets the public/ folder, not the Shopware root most of the time?

Comment: It worked every time I tested it, even with console commands. I guess it's because everything is initiated by the index.php in the public folder.

Comment: This isn't reliable in my experience. Sometimes it's the root folder (scheduled tasks), sometimes the public one (flow event handlers).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get the public path through the file-system, you can also simply inject the according config from it via:

```
'%shopware.filesystem.public.config.root%'
```

This will give you the path to the public-directory.